# Hide RecyclerView scrollbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I remove the scrollbar in my recyclerview?
I've tried with `mRecyclerView.setScrollBarSize(0);` but it's not working. (Actually, it doesn't do anything, whatever the value I set).

Comment: What about `.setVertical/HorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);` ?

Comment: I don't know how I've missed that :D Thanks

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Put `android:scrollbars="none"` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

### **Update for androidx library** :

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 11):

Add `android:overScrollMode="never"` and `android:scrollbars="none"` in your xml. The following example is with **androidx** RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: they are different things, I used both android:overScrollMode="never" and android:scrollbars="none". Over scrollMode is being used to set the scroll effect of the end of scrolling. It's irrelevant about what the question is. We talk about scrollBar visibility and it can be set by scrollbars="none". So, your answer is wrong. If it's not, then please give us the reason behind your answer.

Comment: I already wrote overScrollMode="never" but I still have scrollbar. When I did wrote this android:scrollbars="none" it worked as expected